# Proving exponential inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

I'm currently revising for an upcoming exam and am stuck on the following question. I have completed a similar question that involved cos and the mean value theorem I used the triangle inequality too, so I assume this question will do the same. However I am unsure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Hint: Use the Mean-Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** According to the MVT $$e^x-e^y=e^\xi (x-y) $$ for some $\xi \in (0,1).$

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
e^x-e^y=\int_x^ye^tdt
$$ giving, for $x,y \in [0,1]$,
$$
\left|e^x-e^y\right|=\left|\int_x^ye^tdt\right|\leq e\left|\int_x^y1dt\right|=e|x-y|.
$$

Comment: is there a way I could do this using mean value theorem as well?? :)

Comment: @Chloe Then the user1337 answer seems fine for it. Thanks.